# Dynamic Programming with memoization taking longer than brute force approach

Tags: algorithm, performance, c#-4.0, dynamic-programming

I solved this [challenge](https://leetcode.com/problems/target-sum/#/description) initially using Brute force and it got accepted. I was trying to make use of dynamic programming with memoization to reduce the time complexity from `O(2^n)`.

The dynamic programming with memoization was taking longer than the brute force approach and I'm getting a Time Limit Exceeded error message.

Brute force Approach Code.

```
public class Dummy
{
    private int answer = 0;
    private int numberCalled = 0;
    public bool doFindSum(ref int[] nums, int index, int current, int target)
    {
        numberCalled++;
        if (index + 1 == nums.Length)
        {
            if (current == target)
            {
                ++answer;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        bool add = doFindSum(ref nums, index + 1, current + nums[index + 1], target);
        bool minus = doFindSum(ref nums, index + 1, current - nums[index + 1], target);
        return add || minus;
    }
    public int FindTargetSumWays(int[] nums, int S)
    {
        numberCalled = 0;
        doFindSum(ref nums, -1, 0, S);
        Console.WriteLine("Nums Called = {0}", numberCalled);
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Dynamic Programming with Memoization Code

```
public class DP
{
    private Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>> dp;
    private int numberCalled = 0;
    public int doFindSum(ref int[] nums, int index, int current, int target)
    {
        numberCalled++;
        Dictionary<int, int> temp;
        if (dp.TryGetValue(index + 1, out temp))
        {
            int value;
            if (temp.TryGetValue(current, out value))
            {
                return value;
            }
        }
        if (index + 1 == nums.Length)
        {
            if (current == target)
            {
                if (!dp.ContainsKey(index + 1))
                {
                    dp.Add(index + 1, new Dictionary<int, int>() { { current, 1 } });
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
        int add = doFindSum(ref nums, index + 1, current + nums[index + 1], target);
        int minus = doFindSum(ref nums, index + 1, current - nums[index + 1], target);
        if ((!dp.ContainsKey(index + 1)) && (add + minus) > 0)
        {
            dp.Add(index + 1, new Dictionary<int, int>() { { current, add + minus } });
        }
        return add + minus;
    }
    public int FindTargetSumWays(int[] nums, int S)
    {
        numberCalled = 0;
        dp = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>(); // index , sum - count
        var answer =  doFindSum(ref nums, -1, 0, S);
        Console.WriteLine("Nums Called = {0}", numberCalled);
        return answer;
    }
}
```

And the Code to driver code the measure the time taken by each approach

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

             var ip = new int[][] { new int [] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                                new int [] {6,44,30,25,8,26,34,22,10,18,34,8,0,32,13,48,29,41,16,30},
                                new int []{7,46,36,49,5,34,25,39,41,38,49,47,17,11,1,41,7,16,23,13 }
            };
        var target = new int[] { 1, 12, 3 };
        for (int i = 0; i < target.Length; i++)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var dummy = new Dummy();
            Console.WriteLine("Brute Force  answer => {0},  time => {1}", dummy.FindTargetSumWays(ip[i], target[i]), sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            sw.Restart();
            var dp = new DP();
            Console.WriteLine("DP with memo answer => {0},  time => {1}", dp.FindTargetSumWays(ip[i], target[i]), sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
        #endregion
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

And the ouptut for this is

```
Nums Called = 1023
Brute Force  answer => 256,  time => 1
Nums Called = 19
DP with memo answer => 256,  time => 1
Nums Called = 2097151
Brute Force  answer => 6692,  time => 29
Nums Called = 2052849
DP with memo answer => 6692,  time => 187
Nums Called = 2097151
Brute Force  answer => 5756,  time => 28
Nums Called = 2036819
DP with memo answer => 5756,  time => 176
```

I'm not sure why the time for the Dynamic approach is more even though the number of times the `doFindSum` method called is lesser for this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No wonder your brute force got accepted as in worst case it would be O(2^SizeOfArray).

---

*order of 2^20 in our case i.e. approx. order of 1e6 operations, 20 is the upper-bound of array size in input as mentioned in the question. If this was high it would probably get timed out unlike DP solution as we will see.*

---

**Coming to the DP solution our recursive relation would be like:**

```
for all S in range(-MaxSum,MaxSum) and i in range(1,SizeOfArray)
     count[i][S] = count[ i-1 ][ S-arr[i] ] + count[ i-1 ][ S+arr[i] ]
```

For simplicity, just focus on this part:

```
count[i][S] = count[ i-1 ][ S-arr[i] ] + count[ i-1 ][ S+arr[i] ]
```

It only depends on previous state. So you can optimize this in space like 0-1 Knapsack problem as the problem completely depends only on the previous state.

The run-time complexity would be `O(2*SizeOfArray*MaxPossibleSum)` which in our case is O(2*20*1000) which is definitely less than brute-force solution. The space complexity of optimized code will be `O(MaxSum)`.

**Now regarding problem with your code:**

In dynamic programming, solving a big problem should solve many smaller problems which will be solved only once and reused many times. It is called [overlapping sub-problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapping_subproblems) property. In this case, your code doesn't seem to exploit this. Why? Because in our problem the DP state is made of two variables "`index`" and "`current`" as you have declared but you are entering the memo only based on index. This was the problem. I have made some corrections in your code. Now it runs faster than brute-force one.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
public class Dummy
{
    private int answer = 0;
    private int numberCalled = 0;
    public bool doFindSum(ref int[] nums, int index, int current, int target)
    {
        numberCalled++;
        if (index + 1 == nums.Length)
        {
            if (current == target)
            {
                ++answer;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        bool add = doFindSum(ref nums, index + 1, current + nums[index + 1], target);
        bool minus = doFindSum(ref nums, index + 1, current - nums[index + 1], target);
        return add || minus;
    }
    public int FindTargetSumWays(int[] nums, int S)
    {
        numberCalled = 0;
        doFindSum(ref nums, -1, 0, S);
        Console.WriteLine("Nums Called = {0}", numberCalled);
        return answer;
    }
}

public class DP{
    private Dictionary<Tuple<int,int>,int> dp;
    private int numberCalled = 0;
    private int tp1=0;
    public int doFindSum(ref int[] nums, int index, int current, int target)
    {
        numberCalled++;
        Tuple<int,int> tp=new Tuple<int,int>(index+1,current);
        int value;
        if (dp.TryGetValue(tp, out value))
        {
                tp1++;
                return value;
        }
        if (index + 1 == nums.Length)
        {
            if (current == target)
            {
                if (!dp.ContainsKey(tp))
                {
                    dp.Add(tp, 1);
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
        int add = doFindSum(ref nums, index + 1, current + nums[index + 1], target);
        int minus = doFindSum(ref nums, index + 1, current - nums[index + 1], target);
        if ((!dp.ContainsKey(tp)))
        {
            dp.Add(tp, add + minus);
        }

        return add + minus;


    }
    public int FindTargetSumWays(int[] nums, int S)
    {
        numberCalled = 0;
        dp = new Dictionary<Tuple<int,int>,int>(); // index , sum - count
        var answer =  doFindSum(ref nums, -1, 0, S);
        Console.WriteLine("Nums Called = {0} tp={1}", numberCalled,tp1);
        return answer;
    }
}

public class sol{
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

             var ip = new int[][] { new int [] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                                new int [] {6,44,30,25,8,26,34,22,10,18,34,8,0,32,13,48,29,41,16,30},
                                new int []{7,46,36,49,5,34,25,39,41,38,49,47,17,11,1,41,7,16,23,13,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1 }
            };
        var target = new int[] { 1, 12, 3 };
        for (int i = 0; i < target.Length; i++)
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var dummy = new Dummy();
          //  Console.WriteLine("Brute Force  answer => {0},  time => {1}", dummy.FindTargetSumWays(ip[i], target[i]), sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            sw.Restart();
            var dp = new DP();
            Console.WriteLine("DP with memo answer => {0},  time => {1}", dp.FindTargetSumWays(ip[i], target[i]), sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I must say though today I learnt a little bit of C#. I didn't had any prior experience with it.

Answer (score 1):

I did not quite understand your memoization code, but seems too complicated to me. All you need is to remember number of possible combinations for all possible sums for some number of nums. You add one number a time and update those sums. You start with one possible combination with zero sum.

```
public int FindTargetSumWays(int[] nums, int S)
{
    int numberCalled = 0;

    int sum = nums.Sum();
    if (Math.Abs(S) > sum) { return 0; }

    int[] arr = new int[2 * sum + 1];
    arr[0] = 1;
    int upperBound = 0;

    foreach (int num in nums)
    {
        int num2 = 2 * num;
        upperBound += num2;
        for (int i = upperBound; i >= num2; --i)
        {
            arr[i] += arr[i - num2];
            numberCalled++;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Nums Called = {0}", numberCalled);
    return arr[S + sum];
}
```